# sqlalchemy - automap_base dynamically generates mapped classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

How i can make below code to work dynamically by given list of tables .

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine('postgresql://admin:admin@192.168.1.113:5432/target')
session = Session(engine)

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

metadata = MetaData()

# list of tables...
tables = ['books']
metadata.reflect(engine, only=tables)

Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()

## hardcode version

books = Base.classes.books

query = session.query(books).all()

for row in query:
    print(row.title)
```

So the question how i can dynamically extract all tables from Base.classes
and create new class dynamically.

Pseudo code

```
for table in tables:
   cls.<table> = Base.classes.<table>

## or maybe even better iterate on Base.classes

for cls in Base.class :
   cls.__name__ = cls
```

Comment: this gives you a dict of `name: table` mapping `{i.__name__: i.__table__ for i in Base.classes}` if you want just the class, then just use `{i.__name__: i for i in Base.classes}`, if this is not what you want, then I do not understand your requirement

Comment: thats actually answering the question perfectly ,thanks!